# .NET Core Azure Function and Entity Framework 6 not properly interpreting ConnectionStrings from local.settings.json

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-6, azure-functions

I have a .NET 4.x library that is being referenced both by a ASP.NET 4.x webapp and a .NET Core 3.x Azure Function. In this library is an EF6 DbContext-derived class with a constructor like this:

```
public MyContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
```

And of course there's a "DefaultConnection" ConnectionString defined in the dotnet4 webapp's web.config. This connection string points to a local instance of SQL Express, and looks like this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Works great, always has.

Now we have the Azure Function which we're trying to test locally. The ConnectionStrings section in the local.settings.json looks like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    }
```

I've also tried strongly typed versions of the ConnectionString, explicitly defining the ConnectionString and ProviderName separately to no avail.

The problem I'm running into is that when running in the context of an Azure Function/ under dotnetcore in general, connection string *names* are not recognized when passed into the constructor, and instead are treated as the default catalog. This is the connection string that the Function ultimately dreams up:

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=DefaultConnection;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

...despite no reference to localdb anywhere in the codebase. If I change the DbContext constructor to this:

```
public MyContext() : base("RatFink") { }
```

The connection string used by the context is:

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=RatFink;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

If I pass the actual connection string into the call to `base()` it is recognized as such and everything works as expected, but this requires code changes to the referenced library which is less than ideal.

Why is the connection string name not being recognized and read from the local.settings.json under the context of an Azure Function/.NET Core and how can I resolve?

Comment: You want to access the value of connection string from the azure function startup ? is this your requirement >